# Allow facebook app access public

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I develope mobile application for android that uses facebook sdk.
When I try to use it I get:
Error App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly
I understood I need to allow  access public.
on Status & review I want to turn on the question

```
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?
```

But then I have to fill in numerous details and images.
And after filling all this I need to wait 7 days for approval by facebook team.
I am just in a stage of developing. This is crazy! I don't have yet all the screen shots and images they want. I am sure they will not approve my app.

Comment: Hey @Gilad sefti it is not mandatory that you submit the app for review after turning on allow access public to Yes...You can still make graph api calls without submitting for review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Gilad sefti it is not mandatory that you submit the app for review after turning on allow access public to Yes...You can still continue to make graph api calls without submitting for review

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just needed to add contact email. That confused me.